# Does anyone have a sample for adding a context menu on ECharts?

Tags: javascript, echarts

Based on the documentation there's an event to handle the context menu for echarts but I couldn't find any sample on how to implement it and how to add a context menu.

https://apache.github.io/echarts-handbook/en/concepts/event#handling-the-mouse-events

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning event listener implementation the via zrender `echart.getZr().on` is the more user friendly way, except you want to force clicking on echart elements with `echart.on`

```
myChart.getZr().on('contextmenu', function(params) {console.log("right clicked")});
```

I don't think there is further contextmenu support from echarts, it would be nice to have a similar stylable one.

But from that point onward you can implement your own context menu.